# Can the domain and co-domain be the same set? Is this a function?

Tags: functions

Let $A$ denote the set of all real numbers. Let $B$ denote the same set as $A$. Let $f$ be the function that, to each number in $A$ assigns the cube of the number. Is $f$ a function?

Comment: you mean $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: tine, do you know what is the definition of a function? can you say where you have truble to show that this is indeed a function?

Comment: If your question is whether or not $$f : \underbrace{\mathbb{R}}_{\text{domain}}\to \underbrace{\mathbb{R}}_{\text{codomain}},$$ where $f(x) = x^2$, is a function, then the answer is *yes*, but I wonder if you meant whether or not it's possible for a function's domain and *image* to be the same set? If so, consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is nothing at all against having a function with the same set as domain and codomain. There are lots of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, among these $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto x^3$.

(Note that there is no requirement either that every element of the codomain has to be hit by the function. So $x\mapsto x^2$ describes a perfectly good function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. If if in fact every point in the codomain is hit -- such as for $x\mapsto x^3$, we say that the function is *surjective*. Some but not all functions are surjective).